# moving from 3dim to 2dim

Tags: r, netcdf

I have create a netcdf file that I was guessing is a 2dim file, but when I do :
dim(tspei01.nc) I got:

```
dim(tspei01.nc)
[1] 100 180   1
```

obviously, it's a 3-dim
how to remove the last dimension and to have only

```
dim(tspei01.nc)
[1] 100 180
```

Comment: The `dput()` output should go to your post, not to the comments. Click edit in your question and add it there. There is no character limit in your post.

Comment: Hi, read [our guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038) regarding the philosophy of reproducible examples. There's actually no need to share huge datasets. People that dedicate some time to answer your question should simply be able to exactly reproduce your issue by copy-pasteing your code.

Comment: Yes, sorry guys copy !